What is the rhyme scheme of the poem "Tartary"?
Please tell me what is the rhyme scheme in the poem Tartary?
I have tried to solve it: am I right? Especially about "wine" (C) and mandoline (D) please confirm. Wine and mandoline don't rhyme as we use /ain/ sound in wine and /i:n / sound in mandoline.
Tartary
by Walter de la Mare

If I were Lord of Tartary,A
Myself, and me alone,B
My bed should be of ivory,A
Of beaten gold my throne; B
And in my court should peacocks flaunt,C
And in my forests tigers haunt,C
And in my pools great fishes slant C
Their fins athwart the sun.D
If I were Lord of Tartary,A
Trumpeters every day. B
To all my meals should summon me, A
And in my courtyards bray; B
And in the evening lamps should shine, C
Yellow as honey, red as wine, C
While harp, and flute, and mandoline D
Made music sweet and gay.B
If I were Lord of Tartary, A
I'd wear a robe of beads, B
White, and gold, and green they'd be A
And small and thick as seeds; B
And ere should wane the morning star,C
I'd don my robe and scimitar.C
And zebras seven should draw my car C
Through Tartary's dark gleades.B
Lord of the fruits of Tartary.A
Her rivers silver-pale! B
Lord of the hills of Tartary.A
Glen, thicket, wood, and dale! B
Her flashing stars, her scented breeze,C
Her trembling lakes, like foamless seas,C
Her bird-delighting citron-trees,C
In every purple vale!B


Perhaps Walter de la Mare wants shine, wine and mandoline to rhyme, just as in the previous verse he has flaunt, haunt and slant (and also alone, throne and sun, which your annotation seems to have missed).

But if we follow British pronounciation, wine and mandoline don't rhyme. What should I tell in the class. My students are confused.

Rhymes are often close, not exact ryhmes. Does that happen in your students' language(s)?

Per @WeatherVane, "Their fins athwart the sun" is an imperfect B rhyme, a near-rhyme. Like the common rain and again, where it's pronounced a-GEN.

It's ABABCCCB, in every verse. Note that Walter de la Mare has spelled mandolin as mandoline so that it rhymes with wine. He has also spelled glades as gleades so it rhymes with seeds. (Furthermore, sun isn't an exact rhyme with throne, and neither is haunt with slant, but he didn't respell these.)

According to Britannica "Walter de la Mare (born April 25, 1873, Charlton, Kent, England—died June 22, 1956, Twickenham, Middlesex) was a British poet and novelist. He was a pure British poet, I mean he didn't migrate from any other place. I don't know why did he change some words like mandoline for mandolin and gleades for glades. Why did he not change "Sun" if he really wanted to rhyme it with throne. So is the case with haunt and slant. Also, did he mention anywhere that he is delibrately writing this poem with fixed rhyme " ABABCCCB". I am not convinced with this rhyme scheme in this poem.

I think your approach is too literal. Language is what people speak, and what poets decide to write. Isn't it the same in other cultures?

I’m voting to close this question because it is more appropriate on Literature.SE.

Wikipedia has a list of named rhyme schemes. There doesn't seem to be a name for ABABCCCB.

@EdwinAshworth: Questions don't become off-topic here just because they're on-topic (or even better suited to be answered) at another site.

@herisson 'While there is a poetry section, we don't actually analyse poetry, per se. We do answer questions about the meaning of words, in a specific context, though.' [Matt E. Эллен; Mod]

@EdwinAshworth: I would not say that all aspects of poetry are on topic here (literary analysis, for example, is excluded). But in this case, the question is about rhyme, which is a matter of pronunciation, something that is explicitly included in our description of what's on-topic: "Pronunciation (phonetics and phonology, dialectology)". Hence, I see the question of "what is the rhyme scheme" as falling within the scope of this site (whereas a question like "what is the effect of this rhyme scheme" would not be).

@PeterShor commented about the spelling "gleades", and I noticed when I looked at Google Books that this is actually spelled as "glades" in the version of the book scanned there. Amn, are you able to add a link or citation to the specific place you got the spelling of the poem from?

@herisson: The OP writes gleades, and if you Google "Through Tartary's dark gleades", you find lots of copies of the poem online with "gleades". But I can't find an instance of "gleades" in Google books earlier than 2017. It's clearly a typo which has been promulgated somehow.

@herisson No; analysing the rhyme scheme of a long poem without a simple answer isn't targeted enough.

It's a duplicate of this, this and several other questions discussing the concept of half-rhyme. The question of whether wine and mandoline rhyme is too trivial to ask here, like any other question about standard punctuation of dictionary words, as it can be solved with a dictionary.

@StuartF Although some cases are clearer than others, I try to be slow to automatically characterize rhymes written by someone far removed from me in time and place as mere "half-rhymes" just because they no longer form perfect rhymes for me and mine today, simply because of how often further research has shown that I would have been wrong to do so. I'm not saying this is the case here, just that it's something I now try to check out more carefully before I let my own implicit accent biases unwittingly miscolor the situation, given that I've made too many mistakes historically.

@tchrist: Walter de la Mare is not that far removed in time (1873–1956). I suspect these were half-rhymes for him, as well (except maybe for haunt/slant).

As Peter Shor said in a comment, every eight-line stanza has ABABCCCB as the base or underlying rhyme scheme.1
This doesn't necessarily mean that all lines within a rhyme-group end with exactly the same sounds. Many English poets, past and present, allow some room for rhymes to be inexact. The use of "sun" alongside "alone" and "throne" in the first stanza is an inexact rhyme. They end in the same consonant sound /n/, but sun has a "short u" sound whereas alone and throne have a "long o" sound. There is no dialect or time period that I know of where both of these vowel sounds evolved to become generally identical.2
Another place that seems to show an inexact rhyme is the triplet beads, seeds, and glades in the third stanza. (Although the question uses the spelling "gleades", Google Books' scan of the 1923 printing of Walter de la Mare's Songs of Childhood uses the spelling "Through Tartary's dark glades".)
You may also encounter archaic or obsolete pronunciations in poems. In modern pronunciation, flaunt, haunt, and slant would be inexact rhymes. However, it was formerly common to pronounce flaunt, haunt, and other words ending in -aunt with the unrounded vowel /ɑː/, as in father (and as still used in aunt), making them exact rhymes to a certain southern British pronunciation of slant. (The use of /ɑː/ in flaunt and haunt is mentioned in the 1803 edition of John Walker's pronouncing dictionary, although Walker transcribes slant with /æ/ rather than /ɑː/, making this an inexact rhyme in his pronunciation as well.) I'm not sure whether Walter de la Mare, who lived from 1873–1956 and apparently published Tartary in 1902, was using an imperfect rhyme, or whether he used or had knowledge of the old pronunciation of flaunt and haunt with /ɑː/ and intended a perfect rhyme between three words pronounced with /ɑːnt/.
It is often difficult to infer with certainty whether a historical poet intended to use an inexact rhyme, or used a now-archaic pronunciation of a word. For example, I'm not sure whether pronouncing mandoline with the /aɪ/ diphthong of wine was ever common outside of poetry.


I don't know of a particular name for this rhyme scheme. Other poems using it include "The Garden of Proserpine" (Algernon Charles Swinburne, 1866) and "Hint From the Mountains
For Certain Political Aspirants" (William Wordsworth, 1820). Note the (I assume) imperfect rhymes between "ever", "never", and "river" in the first, and between "daring", "pairing", "and "war in" in the second. (Daring and pairing could well have ended in [ɪn], but it's hard to believe the vowels in the stressed syllables of pairing and war were a perfect match for Wordsworth. Elsewhere he rhymes war with far—which once had the same vowel sound if you go back far enough, but may not have been an exact rhyming pair for him: Walker 1803 already transcribes them with distinct vowels. The vowels of far and pair are etymologically distinct and have not merged in any widely spoken accent I know of).

Although we cannot absolutely exclude the possibility of irregular developments, I've never heard of these three words developing alternative pronunciations that would allow for a perfect rhyme. See the question Did the words "come" and "home" historically rhyme? for another possible example of an imperfect rhyme between "short u" and "o": come and home.
I wrote more about the use of inexact or imperfect rhymes in my answer to How Was "Feast" Pronounced in Early Modern English?. Most imperfect rhymes have matching consonants but mismatching vowels: in cases like these, it's often difficult to be certain whether the historical pronunciation was different from the modern one. English vowel sounds have changed significantly even in recent centuries, and vowels still show a lot of variation between accents; in part because of this, the spelling of vowel sounds is often complex and somewhat unpredictable. However, some imperfect rhymes show mismatched consonants, in which case it's often fairly clear that an exact rhyme could not have been intended: an example of this is the use of open and broken as rhymes in Shakespeare's Sonnet 61.



Multiple sources refer to this particular ABABCCCB refrain-poem form as Swinburne’s octain, an octave trimeter with both iambic and trochaic variants. The trochaic variant has syllables 9/8/9/8/9/9/9/8 where the shorter B lines end in a trochee with masculine rhyme, but the A and C lines are amphibrachs with feminine rhyme (stressed earlier than the last syllable) and (sometimes) with only their final unstressed syllable rhyming not the entire foot. (Apparently he invented many poetic forms: see also Swinburne’s Rhymed Sestina.)

@tchrist: Some poets in the New Formalist school of poetry seem to be obsessed with finding and naming rhyme schemes used by famous poets, possibly because they can't bear the thought that they might be making up their own new rhyme schemes. Swinburne used ths rhyme scheme for The Garden of Proserpine, but I'm not sure that he used it for any other poems. And very few websites call it "Swinburne's Octain".

@PeterShor I certainly agree with you about the oddity of this obsession for naming rhyme schemes.

This poem has a number of imperfect rhymes, words that don't "truly rhyme" but "sort of almost" do. These are common in plenty of poems and songs. They don't mean that the author made a mistake, but that these half-rhymes are acceptable. If you're teaching students about poetry and their structure, this is important to teach too.
For poems that are have stanzas that are all similar, it's reasonable to expect all the stanzas to follow the same pattern. This can be the best tool for resolving these half-rhymes; right now your analysis of the last two stanzas is the same, so we can expect the other two to follow the same scheme. The rhyme scheme of a poem is still valid even if half-rhymes are present; "rhyme scheme" isn't a tool for understanding pronunciation but for understanding how a poem was written.
One of the most surprising words here is "gleades." This is not a common modern spelling; the word that makes sense from context is "glades." I haven't found evidence of exactly this spelling, but the history of the word glad shows a few that are close: an Old English spelling "glæd" as well as Old Frisian "gled." I don't know enough about Old English pronunciation to know whether it would be closer to rhyming with "blade" or "weed," but I would be inclined if reading this poem aloud to pronounce it as "glades," since if I said "gleeds" my audience might not know what was meant. But the altered spelling can be seen as a concession to the half-rhyme.

Worth making it explicit what the rhyme scheme is, and what the part-rhymes are.

I'm not sure where the spelling "gleades" comes from, but I found that it doesn't seem to occur in the 1923 printing of this poem: https://books.google.com/books?id=ks8-AAAAIAAJ&pg=PA15#v=onepage&q&f=false
